# ステータスバーの背景色について

Tags: ios, xcode, unity3d

Unityでiosアプリケーションの設定について質問です。
私はXCodeはそこまで詳しくはないです。
その点を踏まえてご意見をいただければと思います。

現在、時計・電池残量表示のためにステータスバーの表示を行おうとしています。
現在下記のスクリプトをバッチ処理に含めて実行しています。

> PlayerSettings.iOS.statusBarStyle = iOSStatusBarStyle.BlackTranslucent;

実際、アプリに時計や電池残量は表示されるようになりましたが、背景が表示されません。
※背景透明度0、画面の上から表示される。
※XCode上、UnityのSetting上では設定が反映されているのは確認しています。
現在これの原因調査をしています。
これが原因ではないか、という心当たりがわかる方がいましたらご教授願いたく思います。
Unityは4.6.5です。